# How do I use an image as an object in Java?

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to create a game and don't know how to use an image as the player controlled character. I have a class that makes the object the user controls, and everything works,the thing is I had to base the user controlled character as a rectangle for its positioning and movement, so it has to stay as a rectangle, which is where my searching comes up short. Basically I am wondering if I can jsut essentially paste an image over the rectangle I have and have it stick to it. here is my character class:

```
class Flyer{
    static int panelWidth = 2200;
    static int panelHeight = 1800;

    public static Rectangle flyer = new Rectangle(panelWidth / 2 - 100, panelHeight / 2 - 100, 20, 20);
    public static Rectangle flyer2;
    public static int vertical;
    public int startingY = 0;
    public int newY;

    Flyer(){
        super();
    }


    public void repaint(Graphics g) {
        int panelWidth = 2200;
        int panelHeight = 1800;

        if (vertical == startingY) {
            startingY = flyer.y;

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(flyer.x, startingY, flyer.width, flyer.height);
        } else {
            newY = startingY + vertical;
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(flyer.x, newY, flyer.width, flyer.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Graphics class has other methods that would prove of use and which its [Graphics API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) will show you. Among these are several overloads called `drawImage(...)`

Your Flyer class could hold a BufferedImage field, and then place the image where desired, via the x and y fields that you already have using, say via `g.drawImage(myImage, x, y, null);`

If the image needs directionality, then you can have the class hold several images, and select the correct one based a direction field's state.

Comment: the problem is it has to be a rectangle as far as I am aware because in other parts of the code I use things like the .intersects command which requires two rectangles so that the game can tell when the character hits an obstacle. by not using a rectangle and using drawImage other parts of my code will have to be rewritten in ways I don't know how to.

Comment: @narwhalrus97: You can use both a Rectangle **and** an image in this class, and the Rectangle doesn't even have to be displayed, but rather represent the boundaries of the image.